# Does $r \implies \neg q$, $q$ give $\neg r$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In resolution, if we have a premise such as $r \implies \neg q$  and we know that $q$ is true, can we infer $\neg r$? If yes what is the rule called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$r \to \neg q$ is equivalent to $\neg r \lor \neg q$, so given $q$, resolution gives us $\neg r$.

Comment: Do you know the name of this rule? Is it [modus tollens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) ?

Comment: Resolution _is_ the name of the rule of inference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29

Comment: @ενοίδαότιουδένοίδα: The rule in the title of this question is indeed *modus tollens* as you suggest.

Comment: @ενοίδαότιουδένοίδα: Well, I might take that back--it uses modus tollens, but I suppose it isn't quite modus tollens because you have to also use the fact that NOT(NOT Q) is Q.

Answer (score 2):

If your perspective is one of resolution, then it's just an instance of the resolution rule itself. Then $r\implies \neg q$ is an abbreviation for $\neg r\lor \neg q$, and resolution applied to $\neg r\lor\neg q$ and $q$ gives $\neg r$.